# JavaFX, Instantiate a class that extends a node and use it in fxml?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I have a class Board that extends GridPane. Board has a constructor that looks like Board(int width, int height, int bombs){...} There is no default constructor. I want to put an instance of this class into my fxml file and show up in my program.
in the fxml file I've tried.

`<Board fx:id="board"></Board>`

while my Controller class has

```
@FXML
private Board board=new Board(20,20,40);
```

My fxml file has en error on the posted line "Unable to instantiate"
Do i need a default constructor, or is there another way?

I can post more code, but my program is mostly the default stuff when you start a new javaFX project in IntelliJ.
Sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, it is always a mistake to initialize fields that are annotated `@FXML`.

Comment: The duplicate question was very helpfull. I am now using @namedArg in my Board constructor. However I cant seem to call it correctly from FXML. I used <Board id="board" width="20" height="20" bombs="100"/> and i get the error "Attribute width is not allowed here." its the same Error on the other 2 attributes.

Comment: Is that error occurring at runtime? Or is it just showing up in your IDE?

Comment: Oops my constructor wasn't public... fixed now!